# Grails createCrieteria on super class with conditions on subclasses

Tags: grails, grails-orm, createcriteria

I have been trying for this. But don't know it is possible or not. I need to list records  by writing a crieria query on super class with conditions on subclass.

Say, Cats, Dogs extends Animal class. I need to list all animals but dogs with black dots and cats with white color. Here the key problem is,  *dog's properties* are **not** in *cat domain class.*

But i have to write createCriteria on Animal class so that i can paginate with all animals or am i missing something?.

Answer (score 0):

given that you use `tablePerHierarchy = true` you should be able to write a `native SQL` query to select the records from the table by `where-clauses` pointing to partially null-ed columns:

```
Anumal.withCriteria{
  or{
    sqlRestriction "dots is not null and dots != 'black'" // dogs
    sqlRestriction "color = 'white'" // cats
  }
}
```

Comment: is it not possible with out tablePerHierarchy=true because of which some properties in sub classes needs to be null